# Go: function pointer to function with receiver

Tags: go

Can I set function pointer to function with receiver simpler than creating function around it?

```
package main

import "fmt"

type hello struct {
  name string
}

func (obj *hello) hello() {
  fmt.Printf("Hello %s\n", obj.name)
}

func ntimes(action func (), n int) {
  for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
    action()
  }
}

func main() {
  obj := hello{"world"}
  // Can I do following simpler?
  ntimes(func() {obj.hello();}, 3)
}
```

Comment: @thesystem Edited, `say` is `hello`. What I want simplify is to eliminate anonymous function in call to `ntimes`.

Comment: No you can't. You could use an interface if you always knew the method you wanted to call and then just pass in the object or you can wrap the method in an anonymous function as you did in your example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not right now. But with Go 1.1 this will be possible. [Go 1.1 Function Calls](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1bMwCey-gmqZVTpRax-ESeVuZGmjwbocYs1iHplK-cjo/pub)

Go 1.1 will be ready when the [blue](http://swtch.com/~rsc/go11.html) line touches zero.